# How can I use Manipulate[] to click on a Graphics3D output and generate $(x,y)$ outputs on a projection plane parallel to my screen?

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d

Say I have some Graphics3D object that I'm looking at from a top down perspective, e.g.:

```
Graphics3D[{Sphere[{-1, 3, 0}, 1], Sphere[{0, 1, 0}]}, ViewPoint -> Top]
```

How might I use Manipulate[] so that I can click somewhere on this image and generate an ${x,y}$ output corresponding to the position of the mouse on a projection plane parallel to my screen with respect to the coordinate system in the image?  In the above example, for instance, clicking on the center of first sphere would output $(-1, 3)$, while clicking on the center of the latter would output $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure I understand completely what you desire to do - especially the following is not quite clear: when you click on a sphere, how would `Manipulate` know the depth of the desired point? (due to perspective, this will affect the output)

Then again, Mathematica offers a way to return coordinates with respect to "front and back intercepts with the 3D bounding box", see `MousePosition` documentation, namely `"Graphics3DBoxIntercepts"`.

To illustrate, let's create an example:

```
Manipulate[Column[{EventHandler[Graphics3D[{
  {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[coord[[1]]]},
  {Green, PointSize[Large], Point[coord[[2]]]},
  {Blue, Line[coord]},
  {Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.5]], 
   Sphere[{-1, 3, 0}, 1]}, {Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.5]], 
   Sphere[{0, 1, 0}]}},
 ViewPoint -> view, Axes -> axes, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
 ImageSize -> 
  Medium], {"MouseClicked" :> (coord = 
    MousePosition["Graphics3DBoxIntercepts"])}], 
Grid[Transpose@{{"Front", "Back"}, coord}]}], {view, {Top, Left, 
Right, Front, Bottom}, 
ControlType -> SetterBar}, {axes, {False, True}},
Initialization :> {coord = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}}]
```

You can see that I use `MousePosition` on the discussed object `"Graphics3DBoxIntercepts"` to get the coordinates (plus an `EventHandler` to capture the click). The red point will then mark the point with respect to the "front intercept", the green on the back, and you can use `Manipulate` to look at other viewpoints.

I hope this helps... (to get you started)

[image]

Comment: I like this answer quite a bit.  Regarding not knowing the depth of an object, and how this depends on perspective, this is why I was mentioning {x,y} coordinates on a perspective-based projective plane (i.e. my screen) instead of {x,y,z} coordinates associated with the actual object.