# Moving objects in a 3D graph by dragging the object itself

Tags: graphics3d

I found the applet below on this [webpage](http://mathinsight.org/curl_idea). I think their solution for moving objects in a 3D graph is pretty good, and in some ways better than moving 3 sliders.

I would like to mimic this functionality.  Notice you are allowed to drag the the ball without the 3D view of the graph changing.  You can only move the ball within its current plane but I still think its worth it.  Notice when you drag anywhere else (off the ball) the viewpoint of the 3d graph changes as usual.

How would I go about doing this?  It seems I would have to disable the view while I'm moving the ball, but not sure how to move the ball since locators are only in 2d.  Ideas?

*I am dragging the object with my mouse in the gif.  You can't see my cursor unfortunately.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would say that this is only obtainable if we remove the perspective effect that mathematica uses by default when rendering 3D objects. Note that Mathamatica 11.2 has the new option ViewProjection-> "Orthographic" [related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28600/5467)

Comment: Does this answer your question: [162108](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/162108/5478)?

Comment: @Kuba Thanks! That page had a link to another with the solution.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397468/how-can-i-select-one-out-of-several-graphics3d-objects-and-change-its-coordinate/8398028#8398028

Comment: I'm not sure if I should mark it as duplicate as the solution is posted in stack overflow and not stackexchange. protocol?

Comment: Perhaps you might find this link useful:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162990/plotrangeclipping-when-i-drag-a-3d-object